# Время глагола

Tags: словообразование

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие глаголы не имеют формы будущего времени 1 лица единственного числа и почему? Сжечь, положить, убедить, участвовать, победить, позвонить, предложить, пылесосить, висеть, возвратить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

ОТВЕТ: Глаголы победить и убедить.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ
Глаголы несовершенного вида имеют форму сложного будущего времени: буду участвовать, пылесосить, висеть, поэтому  у них нет ограничений. Глаголы совершенного вида имеют форму простого будущего времени, из этих глаголов к группе "недостаточных" относятся глаголы убедить и победить.

Для справок (Розенталь: Глаголы победить, убедить, очутиться, ощутить, чудить и некоторые другие, принадлежащие к так называемым недостаточным глаголам (т.е. глаголам, ограниченным в образовании или употреблении личных форм), не образуют формы 1-го лица единственного числа настоящего-будущего времени. Если необходимо употребить эти глаголы в указанной форме, используется описательная конструкция, например: сумею победить, хочу (стремлюсь) убедить, могу очутиться, попытаюсь ощутить, не буду чудить.

Ограничения являются фонетическими и связаны с неблагозвучностью формы 1-ого лица.